# Can not show data to angular component with angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular-services

I may be making a silly mistake somewhere but I'm tired of searching around, didn't understand the problem. I'm trying to show api response to table but nothing showing at all.

**My api returns following response**

`[{"productId":1,"productName":"tomato","productPrice":200,"productQuantity":5,"catId":1},{"productId":2,"productName":"potato","productPrice":33,"productQuantity":44,"catId":2}]`

**My Service Class**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Iproducts } from '../model-ts/products';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetprodlistService {
  myAppUrl: string = ""; 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.myAppUrl = baseUrl;
  }
  getproducts(): Observable<Iproducts[]> {
    return this.http.get<Iproducts[]>(this.myAppUrl + 'api/admin/manageproducts/getproducts');

  }
}
```

**Iproducts Interface Class**

```
export interface Iproducts {
  ProductId: number,
  ProductName: string,
  ProductPrice: number,
  ProductQuantity: number,
  CatId: number
}
```

Compoenent.ts file is :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { GetprodlistService } from '../../Services/getprodlist.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-products',
  templateUrl: './manage-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-products.component.css']
})
export class ManageProductsComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public productservice: GetprodlistService) {
    this.getproducts();
  }
  public prodlist = [];

  getproducts() {
    this.productservice.getproducts().subscribe(
      data => this.prodlist=data);
    console.log("product list: " + this.prodlist)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

My Component.html file is :

```
<p *ngIf="!prodlist"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<table class='table' *ngIf="prodlist">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Price</th>
      <th>Product Quantity</th>
      <th>Category ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let prod of prodlist">
      <td>{{ prod.ProductId }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.ProductName }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.ProductPrice }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.ProductQuantity }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.CatId }}</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the properties of the response data in wrong way.
Your type definition model is also incorrect.

#### Type definition

```
export interface Iproducts {
  productId: number,
  productName: string,
  productPrice: number,
  productQuantity: number,
  catId: number
}
```

#### HTML

```
<p *ngIf="!prodlist"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<table class='table' *ngIf="prodlist">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Product Price</th>
      <th>Product Quantity</th>
      <th>Category ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let prod of prodlist">
      <td>{{ prod.productId }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.productName }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.productPrice }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.productQuantity }}</td>
      <td>{{ prod.catId }}</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys declared in the **Iproducts** interface file must exactly match the keys inside the JSON response object.

Modify the keys of your interface class to start with lowercase letters at first, similar to that of the JSON response object.

```js
export interface Iproducts {
  productId: number,
  productName: string,
  productPrice: number,
  productQuantity: number,
  catId: number
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your help :)